# Python 2.7 libxml2, XPath, extract xml attributes

Tags: python, xpath, libxml2

I have the following code:

```
import libxml2
import sys

def xpath_grep(query, file):
    doc = libxml2.parseDoc(file)
    for matched_region in doc.xpathEval(query):
        matched_region.saveTo(sys.stdout, format = True) # add match to stdout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        # default arguments
        query = "data(bn/variable/@name)"
        files = ["burglary_bn.xml"]
    else:
        query = sys.argv[1]
        files = sys.argv[2:]

    for xml_file in files:
        xpath_grep(query, file(xml_file).read())
```

While I believe the "data" function should retrieve the value of the XML attribute, it does not. Instead, it gives me an error:

```
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function data not found
Unregistered function
...
libxml2.xpathError: xmlXPathEval() failed
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Documentation for the XPath data function can be found here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-data

Comment: The `data()` function is available only in XPath 2.0 processors -- it isn't implemented by XPath 1.0 processors, like libxml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to call an xpath function to get at the value of an attribute.   For example, given the following XML document:

```
<doc>
  <section>
    <person name="bob" color="blue"/>
  </section>
</doc>
```

This Python code will get me the value of the `name` attribute:

```
>>> doc = libxml2.parseDoc(open('input.xml').read())
>>> str(doc.xpathEval('//person/@name')[0].children)
'bob'
```

I've never used the `libxml2` module before so there may be a better way of doing it.  I always use the `lxml` `etree` module, using which we could accomplish the same thing like this:

```
>>> import lxml.etree as etree
>>> d = etree.parse(open('foo.xml'))
>>> d.xpath('//person/@name')[0]
'bob'
```

If you can use it, the `ElementTree` (etree) API is a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

**`data()` is an XPath 2.0 function and isn't implemented in an XSLT 1.0 processor, like libxml**.

You need to evaluate the following expression:

```
bn/variable/@name
```

and iteratively (in Python) get the string value of each selected node.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define the function data(), or at least you did not import the right module which has submodule name **data**. 
In your code:

```
query = "data(bn/variable/@name)"
```

looks weird. Why you call a function like this, what exactly data function would do if it's available?

Comment: data is an XPath function. Please read the XPath documentation.

Comment: since he called **data()** as a stand-alone function, so I think it's reasonable to clarify his question. @BackSheep: Downvote my answer is not a nice action thought.